# PyQt - how can element exist without pointer?

Tags: python, pyqt

This program shows window and 3 buttons.
Buttons are generated by iteration `for i in range(3):`.

I don't understand this:
If `button` in the end only contains last button, where are all other buttons?
Why they are not deleted, when `button` starts referring to other element?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        for i in range(3):
            button = QPushButton(str(i), self)
            self.vbox.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To what all buttons are attached?
And how I can access them? `button` for last created button, but other buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling addWidget you "attach" the button to the view and this view stores some reference to its children. If you want to access them from your script, I would suggest you safe them as a local (or instance) variable.

Something like:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttons = []

        for i in range(3):
            button = QPushButton(str(i), self)
            self.vbox.addWidget(button)
            self.buttons += [button]

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

Comment: Just wonder, is it possible to access them through `self.vbox`, if it stores their references?

Comment: Yes, you can. Refer to the Qt API about accessing widget children.

Answer (score 3):

A reference to the button is held in the 'vbox' object.

Comment: While correct, this answer is pretty sparse. You may want to go into more detail

Comment: I prefer to think of it as succinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [itemAt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html#itemAt) method of the QLayout class (which is a parent class of VBoxLayout) to get instances of `QlayoutItems`. The `QLayoutItem` class has a method [widget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayoutitem.html#widget) which you can use to get the widgets you added.

For example in the below code snippet the call to `items' method in`MainWindow`would print text string of the`QPushButton`'s you added (i.e. 0,1,2).

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # same as the posted code

    def items(self):
        for i in range(self.vbox.count()):
            item  = self.vbox.itemAt(i)
            print item.widget().text()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()
myapp.show()
myapp.items()
sys.exit(app.exec_()
```